# Angular 10 Update and xml2js

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, xml2js, ngx-xml2json

Hi I did the update to Angular 10 right now..
and i am receiving this error on ng serve

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/xml2js/lib/parser.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers' in '/src/WebApp/node_modules/xml2js/lib'
```

This is the line

```
  setImmediate = require('timers').setImmediate;
```

Does someone had a similar issue ?

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
npm install --save stream timers
```

Comment: Can you add some more detail on why this will work?